# How can I allocate a budget between team members, given assumptions about rate and time spent?

Tags: excel, math

I’m making something in excel/google sheets that will help me build an instant quotation for an arbitrary piece of client work, based on these inputs:

- a fixed budget (eg. `£5000`)
- team members, each one having:

  - a rate (eg. `£500/day`)
  - a time multiplier expressing how much time each person spends on the team, as a decimal between 0-1 (eg. `1` means the max days possible, `0.5` means half that max, and so on)

The output I want is the number of days allocated to each team member.

Crucially, going in we *don't* know anything about the number of days we want to spend on the project. It's all based on the budget.

It feels kinda calculus-y, which i never learned.

I think the right thing to do is multiply the two variables (time and rate) into one “team member factor” and use that to break up the budget, and then reverse it all to figure out days, but struggling with the order of operations. I keep ending up with a value that's about half the total budget.

I've attached a picture of my WIP spreadsheet, as well as a whiteboard simplification.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Given your description, this seems like algebra, solving for the number of days when we know the constants. Setting up the equation to equal whatever your total budget is. It seems each worker will work some proportion of each day. And you know each worker's daily rate (making sure it's loaded with overhead for the true daily cost).